# installation and integration of EJBCA PKI in my java project

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, ejbca

I have developed a project in Java using ECLIPSE IDE.

Right now, the project functionalities are similar to a Repository of files.

My final objective is to create a "**Notary**-based-system" from the project I have now. The features of my Notary, would be the ones that we see on real life, like validation of files by 2 or more clients, validation of signatures, etc...

For that, I'll use the EJBCA PKI (http://www.ejbca.org/) to solve the Security issues that are associated with a Notary "job", such as confidentiality, authentication of clients, and verify the integrity of files.

However,  I am having many difficulty in the installation of EJBCA in Windows. I have found guides on EJBCA website, but they are for Linux (but I read that is windows supports EJBCA). Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ant, than you can install EJBCA by following step

1. ant bootstrap- To initialize project
2. Set the EJBCA database according to docs.
3. Run the JBoss server
4. ant install- To install root certificate(Here you need to put Cert information)
5. ant deploy- To deploy the project to server

**Note:** This is very short steps to run EJBCA to Windows. EJBCA has huge documentation. Go through over documentation and demo CD video.

Comment: Hi @masudul, where is the demo CD video?